# R - how to perform row X - row Y

Tags: r

Given a dataframe having 4 rows, I need to create a second dataframe with a single row following the formula: row4 - row1.

I think I should apply some rowwise operations, and bind_rows/rbind, but cannot figure it.

```
Browse[4]> table1
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   row_headers [4]
  row_headers               `2007`  `2008`  `2009`  `2010` `2011` 
  <chr>                      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> 
1 domestic                   1582.  1521. 3706.  1895. 2203. 2468. 
2 non-european countries        0      0  4062.     0     0     0 
3 other european countries   1218.  4659. 9274.  9179.    0  3922. 
4 total                      1080.  9180.  242.  2374. 2203. 6390.
```

> Browse[4]> rbind(table1[4, ] - table1[1, ])
> Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why this was downvoted? I am very new to R, an explation would help a lot...

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Do you need `rbind(df1[4, ] - df2[1, ], df2[4, ] - df1[1, ])` ?

Comment: @RonakShah, I simplified my question. Following your example, I am getting an error "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row 4 - Row 1 can be achieved by :

```
result <- table1[4, -1] - table1[1, -1]
```

where 4 in `4, -1` is the row number and -1 is to drop the column 1 which is `row_headers`.

Comment: thanks!! how a column can be added in the beginning?

Comment: Using `cbind` , for example - `result <- cbind(new_col = 'Total', table1[4, -1] - table1[1, -1])`

Comment: "result" variable contains the right data but the type of data is change, it is not specified as "dbl" as in table1. any idea why?

Comment: `table1` was tibble, I think `result` must be of type dataframe. It doesn't change anything. You can get result in tibble form by doing `result <- tibble(result)`.